# React Native: Checkbox not reacting to click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi guys Im trying to make quiz app in React native with checkboxes, I have a question component, but I cannot seem to change the value of checkboxes when user click on them.

Here is my sample code could, you maybe point out, what Am I doing wrong:

**Quiz Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View Image, CheckBox} from 'react-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native-elements';

import questions from '../assets/questions.json';


class Quiz extends Component {



    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
        this.question = questions[0].question;
        this.answers = Object.entries(questions[0].answers).map(([key, value], index) => {
            this.state[key] = false;
            return  <View key={index}>
                        <Text>{ value } {  this.state[key].toString() }</Text>
                        <CheckBox value= { this.state[key] } onChange={() => this.checkboxClicked(key) } />
                    </View>
        });

    }

    checkboxClicked = (key) => {
          this.setState({ a: true })
    }

    render() {
        return (<View>
                      <Text h4>{ this.question} </Text>
                      { this.answers }
                </View> );
    };

};


export default Quiz;
```

**Question JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "question": "Who is the strongest?",
        "answers": {
            "a": "Superman",
            "b": "The Terminator",
            "c": "Waluigi, obviously"
        },
        "correctAnswer": "c"
    },
    {
        "question": "What is the best site ever created?",
        "answers": {
            "a": "SitePoint",
            "b": "Simple Steps Code",
            "c": "Trick question; they're both the best"
        },
        "correctAnswer": "c"
    },
    {
        "question": "Where is Waldo really?",
        "answers": {
            "a": "Antarctica",
            "b": "Exploring the Pacific Ocean",
            "c": "Sitting in a tree",
            "d": "Minding his own business, so stop asking"
        },
        "correctAnswer": "d"
    }
]
```

Im trying to make when user click on checkbox, to change state of checkbox for checked to unchecked and from true to false, But when I use setState like nothing is happening ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using the key being passed to your onClick handler. Try:

```
checkboxClicked = (key) => {
  this.setState({ [key]: true })
}
```

and if you want it to be toggled:

```
checkboxClicked = (key) => {
  this.setState({ [key]: !this.state[key] })
}
```

Comment: Its not working Im not being able to toggle checkbox value :(

Comment: `onChange` should be `onValueChange`. [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/checkbox.html)

Comment: @Dhaval I'd need more information than that to try to help.